# React losing variable inside of useEffect?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am trying to implement an image slideshow. setInterval is used inside of useEffect to change the image after x seconds. The currentImage state is holding the current image and after x seconds it will change into the next image but react is telling me that the index variable will be lost after each render.

```
  const images = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven];

  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = React.useState();

  let index = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (index < images.length) {
        setCurrentImage(images[index]); 
        index++; 
        console.log(images[index]);
      } else {
        index = 0; // If so, reset the index
      }
    }, 5000);
  }, []);


<Grid
      item
      xs={false}
      sm={4}
      md={7}
      sx={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${currentImage})`,
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
      }}
    ></Grid>
```

**Assignments to the 'index' variable from inside React Hook React.useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside React.useEffect**

Answer (score 2):

Just use useState to change the index , and remember to clear the timer.

```
const images = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven];
    
      const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = React.useState();
      const [index,setIndex] = useState(0)
      
      useEffect(() => {
       let timer = setInterval(() => {
          if (index < images.length) {
            setCurrentImage(images[index]); 
            setIndex(prev=>prev+1)
            console.log(images[index]);
          } else {
            setIndex(0) // If so, reset the index
          }
        }, 5000);
          return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer)
          }
      }, []);
    
    
    <Grid
          item
          xs={false}
          sm={4}
          md={7}
          sx={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${currentImage})`,
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
          }}
        ></Grid>
```

Also you can do this :

```
const images = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven];
    
     
      const [index,setIndex] = useState(0)
      
      useEffect(() => {
       let timer = setInterval(() => {
          if (index < images.length) {
            setIndex(prev=>prev+1)
            console.log(images[index]);
          } else {
            setIndex(0) // If so, reset the index
          }
        }, 5000);
          return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer)
          }
      }, []);
    
    
    <Grid
          item
          xs={false}
          sm={4}
          md={7}
          sx={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${images[index]})`,
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
          }}
        ></Grid>
```

Comment: It's not changing the image moreover it is outputting the same image in chrome console. However when I add images and index as a dependency then it changes the current image but react is telling me "The 'images' array makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 96) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'images' in its own useMemo() Hook"

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout and add the index in the dependency array of your useEffect. In that setTimeout you will update your index. But dont store your index as a variable, store it in state.